# Getting length of set inside pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, set

I have a set with strings inside a column in a Pandas DataFrame:

```
                x
A  {'string1, string2, string3'}  
B  {'string4, string5, string6'}
```

I need to get the length of each set and ideally create a new column with the results

```
               x                     x_length
A  {'string1, string2, string3'}         3
B  {'string4, string5'}                  2
```

I don't know why but everything i tried to far always returns the length of the set as 1.

Here's what I've tried:

```
df['x_length'] = df['x'].str.len()

df['x_length'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

Custom function from another post:

```
def to_1D(series):
 return pd.Series([len(x) for _list in series for x in _list])

to_1D(df['x'])
```

This function returns the number of characters in the whole set, not the length of the set.

I've even tried to convert the set to a list and tried the same functions, but still got the wrong results.

I feel like I'm very close to the answer, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Are your sure the column contains set not string?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why but everything i tried to far always returns the
> length of the set as 1.

`{'string1, string2, string3'}` and `{'string4, string5, string6'}` are sets holding single str each (delimited by `'`) rather than sets with 3 str each (which would be `{'string1', 'string2', 'string3'}` and `{'string4', 'string5', 'string6'}` respectively) so there is problem somewhere earlier which leads to getting sets with single element rather than multitude of them. After you find and eliminate said problem your functions should start work as intended.

Comment: Can't belive I missed this. Thanks for the answer!